# Is there an alternative to tf.one_hot()?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I was trying to convert one hot encode tensors, but `tf.one_hot` takes too much memory and keeps crashing. I cannot use keras-> `to_catagorical` because I work with tensors. So I was wondering if there is an alternative to tf.one_hot or if there is any way to make it less resource intensive? Below is my code:

```
def mrr_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred):

    y_pred_revel = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
    y_pred_revel = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(y_pred_revel, tf.int64), 64)

    mrr = mrr_metric(y_true, y_pred_revel)

    return mrr

def create_classifier_bert_model():    
    inputs = layers.Input((config.MAX_LEN,), dtype=tf.int64)
    sequence_output = pretrained_bert_model(inputs)
    outputs = layers.Dense(vectorize_layer.vocabulary_size(), activation="softmax")(sequence_output)
    # outputs2 = layers.Dense(vectorize_layer.vocabulary_size(), activation="softmax")(sequence_output)
    classifer_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs=[outputs], name="prediction")
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=config.LR)
    classifer_model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", weighted_metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy', mrr_metric_fn]
    )
    return classifer_model

classifer_model = create_classifier_bert_model()
print(config.LR)
classifer_model.fit(
    mlm_ds_ft_cs,
    epochs=1,
)
```

Basically, I'm trying to calculate MRR (mean reciprocal rank) for my model.

Comment: Maybe try using sparse tensors?

Comment: or just use a smaller data type, you don't need `int64` if you just have 64 labels, `int8` is already enough

Answer (score 0):

Since you use tensors `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical()` also return tensor you better try it, however you need to change the loss into `loss = "CategoricalCrossentropy"` and the `metrics = ["CategoricalAccuracy", ...]`.